# Vectors intersection question

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, problem-solving

Find all values of k for which the two lines do not interesct
Line 1 $r=(2,-1,3)+t(1,0,2)$ 
Line 2 $r=(2,1,4)+s(2,k,6)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more straightforward to find the values of $k$ for which the lines
do intersect.

You have two parameterised lines $t \mapsto l_1(t), t \mapsto l_2(t)$ and
you want to find $s,t $ such that $l_1(s) = l_2(t)$.

Write out the three equations. Two of the equations do not involve $k$
and can be used to solve for $s,t$. Using these values, find the $k$ for which the lines intersect.